# Angular 8 - Service injection and factory pattern

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, factory-pattern

I've gone through several articles and official Angular guides briefly but it seems that they couldn't help me to solve my task. And here is what I wanted and did.

Let's say I have Angular application with product listing page. Moreover this app will have category listing page and some N listing pages in future. As you can see they're quite similar and will have one component in common - data table.

```
<app-data-table [type]="'product'"></app-data-table>
```

Which is implemented like:

```
import {Component, Input, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {DataFactoryService} from "../data-factory.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-table',
  templateUrl: './data-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-table.component.css']
})
export class DataTableComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() type: string;

  private data: any[];

  constructor(private dataFactory: DataFactoryService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataFactory.getServiceBy(this.type).selectAll();
  }

}
```

So as you might guess already I meant to make this component service type agnostic. That's why I've created and injected that `DataFactory`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {ProductService} from "./product.service";
import {CategoryService} from "./category.service";
import {DataService} from "./data.service";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataFactoryService {

  private serviceTokenMapping = {
    "product": ProductService,
    "category": CategoryService
  };

  constructor() { }

  public getServiceBy(token: string): DataService {
    return new this.serviceTokenMapping[token];
  }
}
```

And at the end we have two services for products and categories with some simple basic abstract class:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export abstract class DataService {

  abstract selectAll(): any[];
}

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {DataService} from "./data.service";
import {Product} from "./product";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService implements DataService {

  constructor() {}

  public selectAll(): Product[] {
    console.log(`ProductService...`);
    return [];
  }
}

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {DataService} from "./data.service";
import {Category} from "./category";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CategoryService implements DataService {

  constructor() {}

  public selectAll(): Category[] {
    console.log(`CategoryService...`);
    return [];
  }
}
```

The funny part here is that this implementation works exactly as a expected. So I'm passing type of table as product for product related page, category type is for category etc.

Question is did I do something incorrect from perspective of Angular style (providers, DI etc.) and do we have any way to implement such a requirement to be more Angular-ish?

Comment: You should double check if you can remove the DataServiceFactory class and inject the services you need directly. Also you should extend abstract classes (`extends` instead of `implements`)

Comment: @ChristophLütjen thank you for the prompt response! Could you come up with some example of what you suggested? I could inject services to component if I were creating it (new DataTableComponent(new ProductService()), but it is created by Angular injector.

Comment: We solved the same problem using directives. There you have a selector like `data-table[products]` and you can inject the data table in your directive (and set dataTable.data from there). We did this to solve this "depends on all available data providers" problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you actually instantiating `ProductService` and `CategoryService` every time you trigger `this.dataFactory.getServiceBy(this.type)` and not actually using the dependency injection in Angular.

You can use the `providers` property of `@NgModule` to specify token per dependency and fetch the dependency using `@Inject` or `injector.get`.

```
export interface DataService {
  selectAll(): any[];
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService implements DataService {
  public static TOKEN = new InjectionToken<DataService>('ProductService_TOKEN');
  constructor() {}

  public selectAll(): Product[] {
    console.log(`ProductService...`);
    return [];
  }
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CategoryService implements DataService {
  public static TOKEN = new InjectionToken<DataService>('CategoryService_TOKEN');
  constructor() {}

  public selectAll(): Category[] {
    console.log(`CategoryService...`);
    return [];
  }
}

@NgModule({
    providers: [
     {
        provide: ProductService.TOKEN,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => ProductService),
        multi: false
     },
     {
        provide: CategoryService.TOKEN,
        useExisting: forwardRef(() => CategoryService),
        multi: false
     }
   ]
})
export class YourModule {}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-data-table',
  templateUrl: './data-table.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./data-table.component.css']
})
export class DataTableComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() type: string;

  private data: any[];

  constructor(
     @Inject(ProductService.TOKEN) private dataService: DataService,
     private injector: Injector
   ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataService.selectAll();
    this.injector.get<DataService>(CategoryService.TOKEN).selectAll();
  }

}
```

Comment: No. While this would be true in many server side frameworks, it's not the way angular dependency injection works.