# Angular 14: Implement Factory pattern

Tags: angular, design-patterns, factory

I want to implement **Factory pattern** in Angular.

The point is, I need to create several forms but every form has its owns properties so I thought the best approach was to create a Factory of forms and depends of the type the factory will render one form or another.

**app.component.html**

```js
<app-form-builder [type]="'phoneForm'"></app-form-builder>
```

**form-builder.component.ts**

```js
interface FormMapping {
  [key: string]: ComponentRef<FormNameComponent | FormPhoneComponent>;
}

@Input() type: string = '';

constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {}

getFormTypes(type: string) {
  const formMapping: FormMapping = {
    nameForm: this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(FormNameComponent),
    phoneForm: this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(FormPhoneComponent),
  };

  formMapping[type];
}

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getFormTypes(this.type);
}
```

The form components are not relevant since the `phoneForm` displays a form with a `input type number` and the `nameForm` displays a form with a `input type text`.

The approach works if I use multiple If's but I don't know why don't if I use the object because it renders the two forms at the same time.

```js
getFormType(type: string) {
  if (type === 'nameForm') {
    this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(FormNameComponent);
  }

  if (type === 'phoneForm') {
    this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(FormPhoneComponent);
  }
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mkjeud?file=src/app/form-builder/form-builder.component.ts)

I have followed [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60888238/angular-8-service-injection-and-factory-pattern) but this example shows how to instantiate a `Service` but in my case I want to **instantiate a component**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem resides in the mapping creation part:

```js
 const formMapping: FormMapping = {
      nameForm: this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(FormNameComponent),
      phoneForm: this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(FormPhoneComponent),
    };
```

When you are creating mapping basically are you instantiating also teh components by calling "createComponent".

You should create mapping like this:

```js
 const formMapping: FormMapping = {
      nameForm: FormNameComponent,
      phoneForm: FormPhoneComponent,
    };
```

End just call create based on the value:

```js
 this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(getFormTypes('...'));
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Now I have some problems with TypeScript but the main problem was solve. Thanks!